# Getting the use and def of an llvm instruction

Tags: c++, llvm, dead-code

I am attempting to carry out liveness analysis and in order to do so I need to obtain the `def` and `use` sets for all of my nodes, where they are defined as follows:

`def[n] = set of all variables defined at node n`

`use[n] = set of all variables used at node n`

So for example in the line:

`a = b + c`

```
def[n] = {a}

use[n] = {b,c}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-def-use-use-def-chains

I hope this page can help you. User objects that access the user_begin (), user_end (), and users () methods in the Value object are those that use the Value object. The Instruction class is a subclass of the User class.

*I may be wrong,* but to get the def-use set in the IR level, the elements of the set should be Value objects, and each node should be an Instruction object.
Therefore, the **def set for each node will be the Value object returned by the instruction**(There is a possible case that the instruction doesn't return. And that case, def set is empty set.), and the **use set will be the User object accessed through the user_iterator of the instruction**.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when we define a local variable in LLVM it uses `AllocaInst`. Here's the example that you have put up:

```
a=b+c
```

in C code:

```
int a;
int b=10;
int c=10;
a=b+c;
```

In LLVM IR compiled with `-g` (debug mode):

```
%a = alloca i32, align 4
%b = alloca i32, align 4
%c = alloca i32, align 4
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %a, metadata !14, metadata !16),
... !dbg !17
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %b, metadata !18, metadata !16),
... !dbg !19
store i32 10, i32* %b, align 4, !dbg !19
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata i32* %c, metadata !20, metadata !16),
... !dbg !21
store i32 10, i32* %c, align 4, !dbg !21
%0 = load i32, i32* %b, align 4, !dbg !22
%1 = load i32, i32* %c, align 4, !dbg !23
%add = add nsw i32 %0, %1, !dbg !24
store i32 %add, i32* %a, align 4, !dbg !25
```

Let's see how to use the LLVM API to collect def-use chains. It is easy as LLVM has an in-house built-in API at function level for this one:

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F){
    errs() << "digraph " + F.getName() + "{\n";
    errs() << "\n";
    for (auto block = F.getBasicBlockList().begin(); block != F.getBasicBlockList().end(); block++) {
        for (auto inst = block->begin(); inst != block->end(); inst++) {
            for (Use &U:inst->operands()) {
                Value *v = U.get();
                if (dyn_cast<Instruction>(v)) {
                    errs() << "\"" << *dyn_cast<Instruction>(v) << "\"" << " -> " << "\"" << *inst << "\"" << ";\n";
                }
                if (v->getName() != "") {
                    errs() << "\"" << v->getName() << "\"" << " -> " << "\"" << *inst << "\"" << ";\n";
                    errs() << "\"" << v->getName() << "\"" << " [ color = red ]\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    errs() << "\n}\n";
}
```

For def-use chains, simple tract alloca and user.

This will generate a PDG.

The code taken from https://github.com/DengMinghua/LLVM-Program-Dependency-Graph-Generator

Hope this helps.